# While loop not breaking from nested if statement until action repeated twice

Tags: python, while-loop, python-2.4

I'm still learning the ropes with my programming and have run into an issue that I can't seem to solve after searching for the answers

I have a while loop that is checking if a dictionary is not empty, or if the user entered a specific character (escape character).

The program works as expected if the user enters the escape character on the first prompt but seems to not function correctly if they first enter something else and then try it.

Can anyone help?

```
hand = {'p':1, 'y':1, 't':1, 'h':1, 'o':1, 'n':1}

def play_hand(hand):
    print hand
    word = raw_input('Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished: ')
    while any(hand) is True or word not in '.':
        if word == '.':
            break
        elif (word == 'toy' or word == 'python') and (word != '.'):
            print '"'+ word +'"', 'earned', 'points.'
            play_hand(hand)
        else:
            print 'Invalid word, Please try again.'
            return word, play_hand(hand)
    else:
        print 'Ending'
        return
```

Comment: This code is invalid Python. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I suggest you try to get the basics in order first. split the different parts of the program in functions, separate the logic from presentation (`print`). And why are you using Python 2? if you just started I recommend you to start with Python 3

Comment: Have you tried the debugger? Also, what are we seeing? Is this the definition of `play_hand`?

Comment: Yes, this is the body of the play hand function.

Comment: Using an older version of Python as it's what they suggested to follow the course. The program is a simplified version of Scrabble where the player receives a random hand (hand) and must use the letters to make a word. The function defined above is play_hand(). The while loop is intended to run until the dictionary with the hand becomes empty. The IF ELSE is checking to see what input is made by the user. It applies specific actions depending on what they do. So far everything works except the '.' to exit the current hand.

Comment: Combining recursion and loops in this way is very confusing. I suggest using loops only. When you finish, all the recursive calls come back to their caller one after the other, and continue executing there, which is likely not handled correctly in your code.

Comment: Where are you _emptying_ your `hand`? It will never become empty in your current code as you're not modifying it at all. Also, you have several mutually exclusive checks against a dot and, lastly, why all the recursion?

Comment: In the program hand is being emptied by another function which is working and passed some unit tests, above was rewritten so that the other function call could be removed. The checks against the dot were to handle input, but it appears that the IF is the only one that works and then not all the time. Recursion is because the lecturer told us to do so in the previous lecture so I thought it was the approach they might want us to practice. I will try and update the code to remove the recursion within the loops, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

So as suggested I restructured the code and removed the recursion from the inner IF ELSE statements. It did the trick! 
Thanks for the help.

Here's the sample from above done in the same fashion. You can now enter the valid word and also exit using the escape character.

```
hand = {'p':1, 'y':1, 't':1, 'h':1, 'o':1, 'n':1}

def play_hand(hand):
    while any(hand) is True:
        print hand
        word = raw_input('Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished: ')
        if word == '.':
            print 'Goodbye!'
            break
        else:
            if not (word == 'toy'):
                print 'Invalid word, Please try again.'
            else:
                print '"'+ word +'"', 'earned', 'points.'
                hand = {'p':1, 'h':1, 'n':1}
```